# Where is Taxonomy under site settings sharepoint 2010?

Tags: taxonomy

I can't seem to find the entry point to create Taxonomy terms in Sharepoint 2010 under Site Settings. Where is the link in Site Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be available if you had started with Blank site template. Because the link is made available via TaxonomyFeatureStapler which does not include Blank site template.

Answer (score 1):

Should be under "Site Administration" heading, as "Term Store Management".

You only get this if the Service Application has been set up in Central Admin, though.

Comment: Service App is setup and running, still no option of Term Store Management in Site Settings. I just ran the Farm Configuration Wizard. Maybe there are some additional steps required to get it working?